# Конвертировать цены по формуле WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

На сайте указаны цены в $, вариативные товары. Можно ли поменять цены всем товарам методом WC. Чтобы цена умножалась на 80, также символ менялся на ₽? Знаю можно поменять основную валюту, а также полезть в базу данных, но скорее всего есть какой-нибудь хук, который я смогу использовать. Пытался использовать `woocommerce_get_price`, но ничего не получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось такое решение

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'display_price', 25, 2 );

function display_price( $price_html, $product ) {
  $price_html = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product ) * 220 );

    return $price_html;

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'alter_price', 25 );

function alter_price( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // запускаем цикл для всей корзины и вешаем на каждый товар доп %
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price * 220 );
    }

}
```